# Appendix figure labeling A.3 before A.2

Tags: floats, appendices

I have a problem with figure labeling in my appendix. As soon as I add a chapter into it, my figures will be wrongly placed. Instead of A1, A2, A3, A 4 it results in A1, A3, A2, A4. And it is not just the label, it is really the wrong image. We would need a dummy image for a MWE, so I just post the important part of the code. The figures are just 4 figure environments with 2 subfigures in each.
Removing twoside does not solve the problem. If I replace \chapter{Additional Results} with \chapter*{Additional Results} the figures are righly placed. The page numbering etc. is ok, anyone have an idea?

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[title,titletoc,toc]{appendix}
\usepackage{graphics,float}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
%
%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{dummy}
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Additional results}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{figure}[H]
\centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.7\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Ret_dirdiff_s15_Scatterplot}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.7\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{FA_dirdiff_s15_Scatterplot}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption[Scatterplots of direction angle difference and PLI retardation and DTI FA]{Scatterplots of direction angle difference and PLI retardation (top) and DTI FA (bottom)}
  \label{fig:dirdifffaret}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.7\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Scatterplot_Direction_Ret}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.7\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Scatterplot_Directions_FA}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption[Scatterplot of direction angles as a function of PLI retardation and DTI FA]{Scatterplot of direction angles as a function of Retardation (top) and FA (bottom)}
  \label{fig:scatterdifffaret}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.7\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Ret_incl_diff_s15_Scatterplot}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.7\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{FA_incldiff_s15_Scatterplot}               \end{subfigure}
  \caption[Scatterplots of inclination angle difference and PLI retardation and DTI FA]{Scatterplots of inclination angle difference and PLI retardation (top) and DTI FA (bottom)}
  \label{fig:incldifffaret}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.7\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Scatterplot_Inclinations_Ret}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.7\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Scatterplot_Inclinations_FA}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption[Scatterplot of inclination angles as a function of PLI retardation and DTI FA]{Scatterplot of direction angles as a function of PLI retardation (top) and DTI FA (bottom)}
  \label{fig:scatterinclfaret}
\end{figure}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I feel so stupid right now. Thank you guys!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Answer or link possible dupe?

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing figures that float (which is the point of the figure environment) with figures prevented from floating using [H] if you do that then figures going out of order is a documented outcome. You probably need `\clearpage` to stop the floating figures going past the H ones (or don't use H).